# How to Get visible element by class?

Tags: javascript, html

I have no option but javascript. I am sure lots of people went through this.

**HTML code**

```
<ul class="recordingslist"></ul>
..
..
..
<div class='test' style="display : none">
  <ul class="recordingslist test1" ></ul>
</div>
..
..
..
<div class="testasdasdsad" style="display : none">
<ul class="recordingslist test2"></ul>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
recordingslist = document.getElementsByClassName("recordingslist")[0];
```

I have many ul with the same class. Now only first ul is visible, I want to append "test" to that visible ul. How can we achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: First you need to define "visible". Scrolled so it is on screen? With display other than none? With visibility other than hidden? With opacity other than 0?

Comment: So is the case that you only have on visible at a time?

Comment: @Swapper — "How to get that visible element is my question" — That's a useless response to a question asking you to be more specific about what you mean by "visible"

Comment: @Swapper — "I will show 1 question at a time" — What does this mean? Are you going to toggle their display properties? Their opacity property? Their visibility property? Are you just going to scroll to them? Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin : Updated question to simplicity. Check now.

Comment: So the `<ul>` elements are hidden by hiding their parent `<div>` (setting it's `display` to `none`)? So you need a means by which you can find the first `<ul>` with a parent `<div>` whose `display` is not set to `none`?

Comment: Yes. Correct. You got me

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification in the comments, you're searching for the first `<ul>` element whose parent `<div>` element has a `display` property which is not equal to `none`.

Given that, I'd suggest:

```
// here we use Array.from() to convert the supplied Array-like
// NodeList into an Array, in order to use Array methods:
Array.from(

    // here we find all <ul> elements with a class of
    // 'recordingslist':
    document.querySelectorAll('ul.recordingslist')

  // we filter the resulting Array of <ul> elements, using
  // Array.prototype.filter():
  ).filter(

    // using an Arrow function, in which the 'ul' variable
    // is a reference to the current <ul> element of the Array
    // of <ul> elements over which we're iterating:
    ul => window.getComputedStyle(
      // we find the computed CSS properties of the node:
      ul.parentNode, null

    // and access its 'display' property to ensure that
    // it's computed display property-value is not equal
    // to the value of 'none' (so it should not be hidden):
    ).display !== 'none'

  // we iterate over those elements retained in the Array,
  // using Array.prototype.forEach
  ).forEach(

    // here we use another Arrow function:
    // ul: the current <ul> in the Array of <ul> elements,
    // index: the index of the current <ul> in the Array
    // of <ul> elements.

    // here if the index is exactly equal to 0, we add the
    // 'test' class-name, otherwise we add an empty string:
    (ul, index) => ul.classList.add( index === 0 ? 'test' : '' )
  );
```

References:

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Conditional, ternary, operator (`assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`Element.classList API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery makes this quite a breeze. Suggest adding an additional attribute to your ul divs to mark if the div should be visible or not. Something like below

HTML

```
<ul visible=false class="recordingslist"></ul>
<ul visible=false class="recordingslist test1"></ul>
<ul visible=true class="recordingslist test2"></ul>
```

JS

```
let allElems = document.querySelectorAll('.recordingslist')
allElems.forEach((obj)=>{
    if(obj.getAttribute('visible')==='true'){
        obj.append('Hello there')
    }
})
```

Comment: Mate pure javascript. this is jquery

Comment: How about now??

Comment: Dont understand why the downvote, seems like an ok answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery selector `:visible` for example, in your case, if you want to select only ul visibles:

> $('ul:visible').append('test');

or using the class

> $('.recordingslist:visible').append('test');

official docs: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/